# Word truncate then apply ellipsis using css

Tags: css

```
.applyWordWrap{
    max-width: 8em;
    word-wrap:break-word;    
}
```

(o.4em = 1Character)
8em = 20Characters .

I have a string with 60 characters. 
I want to show a line with 20 characters, then wrap the remaining text to the next line which contains 10 characters followed by ... (triple dots)

I tried the above snippet, but its not working

I referred different posts but they are not much helpful.

How i can achieve this using css?

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is to set a maximum width in ch units [Take a look here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/length). 
This approached its the closest approximation to get the width of the characters that we have in css.

**try this:**

```
 .applyWordWrap{ max-width: 20ch; word-wrap:break-word}
```

Comment: ch unit equal to the advance measure of the “0” (ZERO, U+0030) glyph found in the font used to render it, so the calculation for 20 character length string will be correct only if the string contains 20 "0" characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is right only if you use fixed-width fonts. In TrueType fonts character width is variable, so the string "www" is wider than "iii". It's the reason why CSS deal with actual string length and not with number of characters.

The following sample illustrates it:

```css
#ttf{
  font-size: 16px;
}
#fixed{
  font-family: Courier New, monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id='ttf'>The text in 32 characters length</div>
<div id='fixed'>The text in 32 characters length</div>
```

If you want to bound the string by the fixed number of characters you should use JavaScript.

Comment: thank you for your reply.Still i am not clear what can i do now?I am using normal english characters only not any special type of fonts.

Comment: The most of web fonts are TrueType. The default font is TrueType. It means that symbol width is variable, doesn't matter if you use English characters and numbers or any other symbols. So, the width of string depends on its content. The most correct way to clip the string is to run with the standard. Then you don't know how many characters will be visible, but you sure that the width of visible part fits the container size. You have a  really good reason to have fixed number of letters, I'd recommend you to use fixed-size font like 'monospace'.